# Easier way to apply multiple arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, composition, functor, applicative

Given value `f` with type `:: Applicative f => f (a -> b -> c)`, What's the best way to map arguments to the inner function.

So far I've found the following:

`(\x -> x a b) <$> f`

`(flip ($ a) b) <$> f`

`($ b) <$> ($ a) <$> f`

I guess my question is why Haskell doesn't have a `:: a -> b -> (a -> b -> c) -> c` function. Or does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Applicative` class has the `<*>` operator (usually pronounced "ap", and is equivalent to `Control.Monad.ap` for most `Monad`s), which combined with the `<$>` operator (itself just an infix alias for `fmap`) lets you write code like

```
-- f :: a -> b -> c
-- fa :: Applicative f => f a
-- fb :: Applicative f => f b
f <$> fa <*> fb :: Applicative f => f c
```

If you need to apply pure arguments, then use the `pure` method of the `Applicative` class:

```
-- f :: a -> b -> c
-- a :: a
-- b :: b
f <$> pure a <*> pure b :: Applicative f => f c
```

An example might be

```
sumOfSquares :: Num a => a -> a -> a
sumOfSquares a b = a * a + b * b

> sumOfSquares <$> Just 1 <*> Just 2
Just 5
> sumOfSquares <$> Just 1 <*> Nothing
Nothing
> sumOfSquares <$> pure 1 <*> pure 2 :: Maybe Int
5
> sumOfSquares <$> readLn <*> readLn :: IO Int
1<ENTER>
2<ENTER>
5
```

The `Applicative f => f (a -> b -> c)` is being constructed by `f <$>` here, so if you already had something like

```
> let g :: IO (Int -> Int -> Int); g = undefined
```

Then you could just use it as

```
> g <*> pure 1 <*> pure 2
```

The `<*>` operator has the type

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

so if your function has type `x -> y -> z`, then `a ~ x` and `b ~ y -> z`, so repeated **ap**plication of `<*>` (get it?) passes more arguments to your wrapped function.

Comment: It seems using  `Applicative` is neater, and requires less parenthesis. I like the `>$<` proposed by @rampion too, but this seems more idiomatic.

Comment: @mgoszcz2 This would definitely be more idiomatic as it only uses pre-defined functions in the standard library.  Most of the time you run across this problem you'll already be working with an applicative, not just a functor (there aren't very many useful functors that aren't also applicatives), so you don't have to worry about the added constraint too much. rampion's solution is good, but the line `f >$< a >$< b` is just weird for my eyes and fingers that are used to `<$>` and `<*>`.  I would probably pick an easier to type operator for it in production code if I were going to use it a lot.

Comment: bheklilr: agreed on all points. I thought about using `<¢>` instead, but that's a bit cruel on the fingers on my keyboard :)

Answer (score 3):

We've got

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But you want the opposite

```
(>$<) :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
```

Which we can easily define:

```
(>$<) f a = ($a) <$> f
```

So given

```
f :: Functor f => f (a -> b -> c)
a :: a
b :: b
```

Then

```
f >$< a :: f (b -> c)
f >$< a >$< b :: f c
```

This isn't as idiomatic as `<*>`, but it works for all `Functor`s, not just `Applicative`s, which is nice.